# Значение слова “перепсто”

Tags: значения, сленг

Что значит слово “перепсто” и как мы его используем?

Comment: А разве МЫ его используем?! Это typo, которое кто-то использует просто по приколу. Как правильно написали, это из лурка, воффки и двачана. Вот там и стоит искать ответ о его происхождении, и почему "перепост" некто именно так пишет.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Перепсто` comes from the word `псто`, which is a misspell of the word `пост` (post). The origin of the misspell is, probably, the typical mistake when a person mixes up the neighboring letters while typing. So, `перепсто` with its spelling normalized should look like `перепоcт`, which means "re-post", and is used the same way as its normalized variant.

Comment: I think the mixing of the letters should emphasize that this word was typed in a hurry. Like "teh" instead of "the", or 1 instead of ! etc.

Comment: @Artemix - You are right, but now this misspelled variant became a meme, it's often used in what is called "[язык падонкаф](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%96%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2)" which uses lots of misspells. Also, other variants of the word exist, `птсо` and `потс`.